# Size of Hom-Sets in A Functor Category

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I am trying to prove the following presumably easy fact: if $B$ is a category with small hom-sets and $C$ is a small category, then $B^{C}$ has small hom-sets. I am assuming the standard Z-F axioms with the additional assumption of a universe, which is a set $U$ satisfying some standard closure conditions. A set $x$ is $\textit{small}\Leftrightarrow x\in U$.

The proof seems straightforward enough, but the very last step is giving me trouble. If $F,G:C\rightarrow B$ are fixed objects in $B^{C}$ and $\tau :F\overset{.}{\rightarrow}G$ is an arrow in $B^{C}$, then $\tau$ is a function:$C\rightarrow \bigcup_{c\in C}$ [ $Fc$, $Gc$]. Since $C$ is small, and the union of the small sets on $RHS$ is small, the result follows.

But I do not see why the union is small. It is certainly true that we can get a set $\Im =\left \{[Fc,Gc ]:c\in C\right \}$, using the limited comprehension axiom, since each hom-set is in $U$. The union then also exists as a set, which is just $\bigcup_{c\in C}[Fc,Gc]$.

My question is: $\Im $ is a set but why is it in $U$?

Comment: So, you are asking: why is the union of a small family of small sets small? This follows by the replacement axiom of universes.

Comment: In ZFC, $\cup \mathfrak{I}$ is a set by the axiom of union (although you need the axiom of replacement to construct $\mathfrak{I}$ in the displayed manner). What definition of universe are you using? The definition of Grothendieck universe on wikipedia lists as an axiom that the union of a small family of small sets is small.

Comment: @Hurkyl: i.e. the union as displayed is obtained by noting that $\Im $ is the image of the function which sends $c$ to the corresponding hom-set. Then $\Im $ is small, by replacement and therefore the union is also since it is one of the closure conditions on $U$ as you point out. Thanks!